# Custom Gutenberg Block - React fields are not showing. No error... Am I missing something?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm learning to make Gutenberg custom blocks by following a Youtube tutorial.
The plugin is activated, In my page, I can see and place my custom Gutenberg block. But the added fields (React) are not showing.
I added a console.log to see if the script is loading properly and it is.
So it appears to me that maybe something is not OK with the syntax?
Any ideas?

```
console.log('Helloooo!');
// ref for React: https://babeljs.io

wp.blocks.registerBlockType('ideapro/custom-block', {
title: 'Company contact information',
icon: 'nametag',
category: 'design',
attributes: {
    companyName: {type: 'string'},
    companyPhone: {type: 'string'},
    companyAddress: {type: 'string'},
    companyAddress2: {type: 'string'},
    companyCity: {type: 'string'},
    companyProvince: {type: 'string'},
    companyZip: {type: 'string'}
},
edit: function(props){
    return
    /*#__PURE__*/
    React.createElement("div", null,
     /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company name"),
     /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company name"
    }),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company Phone"),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company phone"
    }),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company address"),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company address"
    }),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company address line 2"),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company address line 2"
    }),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company City"),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company City"
    }),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company Province"),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company Province"
    }),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Company zip"),
    /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
      type: "text",
      value: "",
      placeholder: "Company zip"
    }));
},
save: function(props){
    return null;
}
})
```

Also, here a screenshot of the console[image]

Thanks for any help!